# «câmera» ou «câmara»?

Tags: ortografia, diferenças-transatlânticas, português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Surgiu essa dúvida no [chat do SOpt](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31752134#31752134) por causa de

> câmera fotográfica

e eu fui pesquisar e no priberam tem:

> ### câ-ma-ra
>
> (...)
>
> 8. Aparelho que serve para tirar fotografias (ex.: câmara digital, câmara fotográfica). = MÁQUINA FOTOGRÁFICA
>
> (...)
>
> Sinónimo Geral: CÂMERA
>
> Ver também dúvida linguística: [câmara/câmera](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1938).
>
> "câmara", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%A2mara [consultado em
> 17-08-2016].

Esse link para a dúvida ainda me deixou mais confuso. Afinal qual é o termo correto? São os dois? Ou é uma questão de grafia pt-PT e pt-BR?

Comment: Interessante saber que ambas as formas são aceitas. Sempre achei que "câmara" fosse voltado ao local onde deputados se reunem para discutir leis(no caso do Brasil).

Comment: @diegofm mas câmara também é isso, não só no Brasil como também em Portugal. Agora depende do [tipo de câmara](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%A2mara)

Comment: Câmera refere-se ao aparelho que registra imagens (tanto câmera fotográfica quanto câmera filmadora), enquanto câmara é usado para referir-se a um local fechado, ou o nome de alguns lugares como "Câmara dos Vereadores". Para fim de desambiguação pode-se observar que as duas palavras tem traduções literais no inglês que são bem distintas: câmera é camera, câmara é chamber.

Comment: @Havenard esqueceu-se de indicar que isso é no Brasil, só.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historicamente ***câmera*** e ***câmara*** foram simples variantes com os mesmos significados, mas atualmente ***câmera*** usa-se quase só no Brasil, e especialmente no domínio da fotografia, televisão e cinema. ***Câmara*** também se usa com estes significados no Brasil, e é em todas as aceções praticamente a única variante atualmente em uso em Portugal.

No [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/) encontramos as duas variantes desde o século XV, mas sendo *câmara* muito mais frequente que *camêra*. Inicialmente as palavras aparecem com o significado de ‘quarto de dormir’, ‘sala’, ‘sala onde se reúne uma assembleia’, ‘a assembleia propriamente dita’. O uso mais antigo que encontrei ligado à ótica é de 1733 — «Camara obscura» — a propósito do funcionamento do olho, nesta [*Historiologia Medica*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fsD9m5THci0C&pg=PA215&dq=%22camara%20obscura%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVwdnA48rOAhWLsxQKHd6mBNcQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22camara%20obscura%22&f=false). A [*câmara escura* (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2mera_escura) esteve na génese da fotografia: literalmente uma sala escura, onde a luz só entrava por um estreito orifício, projetando uma imagem invertida do exterior na parede oposta. Ao longo do século XIX e XX encontra-se no Google Books quer *câmara* quer *câmera* no contexto de fotografia. Por exemplo, neste [artigo de 1856 sobre fotografia](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fCU2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA188&dq=%22camera%20escura%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDjZuD38rOAhXFPhQKHViMAVgQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=%22camera%20escura%22&f=false) encontra-se quer *camara escura* quer *camera escura*.

Entretanto, *câmera* caiu em desuso em Portugal. O Google geral encontra *câmera* em Portugal, mas no Google Books, no século XXI, *câmera* parece vir apenas de autores brasileiros. No [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/), todas os 161 exemplos de *câmera* do século XX são do Brasil. Agora, isto é o uso que se observa. Os dicionários não se entendem.

O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%A2mera), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=c%C3%A2mera) e o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) simplesmente indicam que *câmera* é o mesmo que *câmara*. O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/c%C3%A2mera) confirma, mas diz que se usa especialmente nas aceções relacionadas com fotografia, cinema e televisão. O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa restringe completamente a estas aceções e ao Brasil. Isto confere com o [Vocabuário Ortográfico Comum](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=135814&highlight=c%C3%A2mera) que indica *câmera* apenas como variante brasileira.

Comment: Excelente trabalho de pesquisa Jacinto, como sempre!

Comment: @JorgeB. Portanto podes usar *câmera* à vontade em Portugal. O pior que te pode acontecer é chamarem-te *doudo*.

Comment: @Jacinto A propósito, por que doudo e não loico?

Comment: câmera é uma câmara que produz fotos ou vídeos pelo sua forma original; mas atualmente no Brasil câmara é um local e câmera uma máquina.